electromagnetism and earth field
Can we generate sufficient Electricity to power household gadgets from the experiment shown
https://youtu.be/qedhViY72f8?si=lB5shkVdofsKVhd_

Possibly but it will cost more than better methods so it's not done. Also many Youtube videos with spark plugs, motors and magnets etc are fake. I did not watch the video so I don't know what was in it.

Do you ride a bicycle? Imagine a bicycle that is geared so low that you have to rotate the cranks tens of thousands of times for each meter of forward progress. Now, imagine that you need to pop on over to the local grocer for a quart of milk. Are you going to ride that bike? or would you be better off walking? In theory that bike is no more or less efficient than any other bike, but in practice, because it  is so poorly matched to the way your muscles deliver power, it is completely useless. The generator in the video has a similar problem.

What they are demonstrating is an ordinary generator with a very, very weak magnetic field, that of the earth.
It's interesting, from a physics demo point of view, but it's just a normal generator.
The electrical power it generates is provided by the mechanical input power, less losses. As the field is very weak, the generator is very inefficient, and the losses will be large.
So maybe, with a big enough loop, and a big enough engine to drive it, you might power a small appliance.

It's done already - I mean generating electricity by making the magnetic flux through a coil to change. Most of rotating electricity generators apply it. But the magnetic field is made with solid magnets or other coils which get some current. Using the earth magnetic field is not especially productive, because the needed coils would be too big and rotation speeds would be very high for any useful amount of electricity for warming houses, boiling water etc...where one expects hundreds of watts power output.
The shown experiment seemed to generate easily several volts, but the generated energy per a second was only about 10 microwatts. That's negligible when compared to hundreds of watts. You can try how hard it is to generate power = 100 watts with muscle power. Lift somehow 10 liters of water 1 meter upwards during a single second. That's 100 watts average power which lasts one second. A trained person could do it hours with no break, but I'm afraid producing 100 watts one hour is too much for an ordinary punter even if he had a bicycle-like lifting tool which utilizes the feet without lifting the person itself.
A single transistor radio or a small lamp may work well with only one watt or even less. That power could be produced a long time by an ordinary punter by rotating manually a properly designed generator, but boiling one liter of cold water would be a demanding task. It might succeed a little easier if there's a disk brake heating the water directly,but using the generator shown in your linked video...forget it!

Look again! It wasn't several volts, it was several millivolts, which means it wasn't microwatts, it was picowatts.
